# Wix installer missing out Quote in Registry

Tags: c#, wix

I have created a wix installer to install a windows service. It installs the service but as i start it i get an error, i tracked down the error and it is due to missing a **"** in the HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\TestInstance ImagePath registry value. It was missing the **"** at the the beginning of

```
"C:\Program files\MyCorp\MyApp\Server.exe" TestInstance --service"
```

That **"** at the beginning wasnt there and i added it and the service runs fine now.

My question is how can i get Wix to install it with the correct ImagePath?

Answer (score 2):

When installing the registry value, make sure use &quot ; for every quote you need to use.

Example:

```
<RegistryKey Root="HKLM" 
Key="System\CurrentControlSet\services\TestInstance" 
Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">

    <RegistryValue Type="string" 
    Name="ImagePath" KeyPath="yes"
    Value="&quot;&quot;C:\Program files\MyCorp\MyApp\Server.exe&quot; TestInstance --service&quot;" />

</RegistryKey>
```

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registryvalue.html